# How to stop pagination from getting over the number of page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.7

I want to make sure that the `request('page')` doesn't go over the total page. For example, I have results for which 2 page is enough. Then current page shouldn't be beyond 2. Even if user requests page=3 it should automatically take him to page 2.

I tried

```
            try
            {
                $total_page = $results->lastPage();
            }
            catch(\Exception $e)
            {
                $total_page = 1;
            }
            if(request('page')&&$total_page<request('page'))
            {
                //dump($total_page);
                Paginator::currentPageResolver(function () use ($total_page) {
                    return $total_page ;
                });
            }
```

When I dumped the $total_page; it shows 2 as expected. But the current page is not changing to page=2 as expected.

P.S. The webpage I am talking about is a POST type. User manually inputs on which page he wants to go and then he is taken there.

Comment: your code is ok. similar  code I have done that is Paginator::currentPageResolver(function () use ($currentPage) {
        return $currentPage;
    });

    $users = User::paginate(5);

I think you need to add the query code in the question to get help.

Comment: I solved the problem. I did paginate first and then wrote that function. What I should have done is first resolve current page and then paginate. It is working now. Thank you.